# Do not import a field from database, unless user session is Admin

Tags: php

In my dating agency website, named [Matrimo](http://www.matrimo.com), i want to make phone numbers public on the profile page, BUT if user is *not* admin, then the phone number should not be imported from database.

By default, I can set to import or not data_phone. If i set to import by default, then data_phone should be hidden to the users, less to a specific group_id=5  - Admin group.

Now, for privacy reasons data_phone ( a text field) is set to not show up on public page. So Admin have to go on Control Panel to see it each time.

The fields are imported on public page using:

```
<? view::load('users/elements/profile', array('name' => false, 'fields' => $fields, 'user' => $user, 'overview' => config::item('user_profile_full', 'users') ? 0 : 1)); ?>
```

While: 'users/elements/profile' contains the next code:

```
<? if ( $user['verified'] && $user['active'] == 1 ): ?>

<? view::load('system/elements/field/grid', array('skip' => array(config::item('usertypes', 'core', 'fields', $user['type_id'], 1), config::item('usertypes', 'core', 'fields', $user['type_id'], 2)), 'fields' => $fields, 'data' => $user, 'map' => false, 'overview' => isset($overview) ? $overview : false)); ?>

<? endif; ?>
```

**Question**:

How to edit this code in order to not import data_phone fields from database, unless user is Admin ? Simply adding 'data_field' => false , before ‘map’ ?

I intend to use if condition as:

```
<? if (session::item('group_id') == 5): ?> 
....
<? else; ?>
....
<? endif; ?>
```

Where 5 is the Admin group_id.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the framework you are using?

Comment: You intend to use that if statement? So, what happens when you do? Tried it? Errors? An unrelated suggestion, you should always use `<?php` instead of `<?` (unless for the echo short tag `<?=`) since short tags have been disabled as default since a few PHP-versions back.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I use datingscript . com/documentation

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I am not a developper and i can not play with that since phone numbers should not become visible to anyone in case i test a wrong code. My problem is that i do not know how to write the code correctly.

Comment: 1. If you're using some specific software, you need to add that to your question. It's crucial. There are 10000 of different PHP-frameworks/cms's/software out there. We can't guess. 2. If you can't "play around with that", then how would you ever be able to change how things work?

Comment: Could I suggest that you employ someone to do it for you then

Comment: Application framework

The software uses a custom MVC type of framework built with PHP 5 specifically for it. 
Model, View, Controller
MVC is an approach to separating your code depending on what role it plays in your application. In the application flow it starts with a controller that is loaded. That controller executes a method which retrieves data using models. Once it is done the controller decides what view to load, which contains the output your visitors get to see.

Comment: You need to find sy specifically with datingscript experience. If I were you, I would rather ask this question in a specific datingscript forum where this knowledge is available.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is my first time here. I am a little bit desssoriented. If it is so hard to do it , sure i accept to employ someone. As my busy developper said normally ..it is a very small customization. For future bigger jobs, I will definitely pay somene to do it.

Comment: @Shadow  - I agree, already done but no answer yet.

Comment: 1000Euro for 6 date, you can afford the best

Comment: @RiggsFolly sure. Any relationship is built on trust and respect. I am on my way to discover the stackoverflow comunity and probably I will discover the best developper too.

Comment: By default, I can set to import or not, data_phone. If i set to import by default, then data_phone should be hidden to the users, less to a specific group_id=5  - Admin group.